# mod_wsgi and WSGIScript directive

Tags: mod-wsgi

On my virtual server configuration I have this:

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/project/app/
```

and also I have this directive:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/project/app/wsgi.py
```

from mod_wsgi documentation: "***avoid placing WSGI scripts under the DocumentRoot in order to avoid accidentally revealing their source code if the configuration is ever changed***"

It's clear to me that I must delete the DocumentRoot directive here! I just want to know how it is possible to reveal the code of my wsgi.py file. What kind of request could have a response with that file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/project/app/wsgi.py
```

to:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /suburl /var/www/project/app/wsgi.py
```

Restart Apache and then visit `/wsgi.py`. It will download and show you your source code.

There is usually no reason to set `DocumentRoot` to be the directory your WSGI script file is in when using `WSGIScriptAlias`. By doing it when you don't need to, you are one step away from making your code available if you decided to change your configuration to mount the application at a sub URL and didn't understand the implications of it.

Since it isn't necessary, just don't expose yourself to the extra risk.

Comment: I did this changes and it actually serves my source code! Thank you for your time and help!